Social icons/links in the main navigation bar
I have a request to add social media icons to the main menu of the page. I think it is not a common practice, but I cannot find a convincing reason to give my client against what he asks for.
The website is about daily products, a bakery with its own production. For them their almost daily photo gallery with fresh products is very important, which they update mainly on Facebook, Instagram and Tiktok, where they have important feedback from customers.
Actually my doubt is whether they are right or I am telling them that it is not usual. My search on the internet only gives results on how to add social media icons to the menu.
I already tried the option of a "Follow Us" menu with a drop-down with the social media icons, but it did not work, they want an independent menu per social network

Edit after the answers
I think they see their social media as one of the main sales channels outside the store itself, this is what makes me doubt and leaves me without arguments. In fact, one of the conditions they raise is: "We don't want small social media icons in the footer of the page."

I agree with you that social media links shouldn't be on the same level as other items in the menu. Primarily, this is because it wouldn't make sense from an Information Architecture (IA) perspective. You can use the footer instead, or as I've seen on some headers, place them next to the company name.


Additionally, I recommend the book "Articulating Design Decisions." It helps you deal with clients who make requests that compromise the user experience and shows you how to support your decisions against such requests.
In short, the book introduces the IDEAL acronym for articulating your decision. Here's how it might apply in this situation.
"I really appreciate your feedback on these changes. I understand your suggestion to add social media links to the main menu. However, I see a potential issue: we often use the main menu for links that could mislead users about our website's purpose. My suggestion is to focus on showcasing our main business offerings (as part of the bakery) in the main menu and treat social media links like any other website does.
We don't want our users to be confused by seeing the Gallery and social network links in the main menu. By keeping these separate, I believe  our users can visit the website and complete their tasks without distraction. We shouldn't create interference between a potential sale and time a user might spend on Facebook or Instagram. I'd like to put the social links in the footer so users can engage with them after making a purchase".

I understand what you mean, but I agree with adding "follow us" rather than clumping the main menu with too many labels. On the other hand, I would like to know if there is any other way of accessing social media content besides the main menu.
The other method of suggesting is through user research, like A/B testing. You can try their approach while you try yours to see which is better from the users' perspective.
